# Some gridview rows' buttons do not work, some does ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have a project that has a problem and I couldn't find the reason why.
I use Ajaxcontrol GridView to display the data which come from the database.

Each row when populated has a **DELETE and EDIT** buttons.
When DELETE is clicked, it should display a confirmation pop up.
When EDIT is clicked, it will display ModalPopUpExtender for editing the data.

Some of the buttons in rows (like 1st 15 rows) work, but the buttons of rows below do not work. See picture

[image: ModalPopUp for Editing]

[image: GridView with EDIt and DELETE buttons]

I use this onRowDataBound to sum up the values for each employee and the total of all records

```
protected void gvDetails_OnRowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    for (int rowIndex = gvDetails.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = gvDetails.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = gvDetails.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < 2; //gvRow.Cells.Count
                                                      cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }


   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        EmployeeNo = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EmployeeNo").ToString());
        double TotalPHP = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PHP_Amount").ToString());
        double TotalUSD = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "USD_Amount").ToString());
        string AdjType = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AdjType").ToString();

        if (AdjType == "Income")
        {
            TotalPrice1 += TotalPHP;
            TotalPrice2 += TotalUSD;
        }
        else
        {
            TotalPrice1D += TotalPHP;
            TotalPrice2D += TotalUSD;
        }

        string sNum = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;//just changed the index of cells based on your requirements 
        double sum;
        if (double.TryParse(sNum, out sum))
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[7].Text.ToString() == "Income")
            {
                totalI += sum;
            }
            else
            {
                totalD += sum;
            }
        }

        string sNum2 = e.Row.Cells[5].Text;//just changed the index of cells based on your requirements 
        double sum2;
        if (double.TryParse(sNum2, out sum2))
        {

            if (e.Row.Cells[7].Text.ToString() == "Income")
            {
                totalI2 += sum2;
            }
            else
            {
                totalD2 += sum2;
            }
        }



    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[3].Style.Add("Padding", "0px");
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "<table align='right' style='width:194px;'><tr><td style='text-align:left;'>" + "Total Income:" + "</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:left;'>" + "Total Deductions:" + "</td></tr></table>";
        e.Row.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "<table style='width:100px;'><tr><td style='text-align:right; width:80px;'>" + totalI.ToString("N") + "</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:right;'>" + totalD.ToString("N") + "</td></tr></table>";
        e.Row.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "<table style='width:100px;'><tr><td style='text-align:right; width:80px;'>" + totalI2.ToString("N") + "</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:right;'>" + totalD2.ToString("N") + "</td></tr></table>";
        e.Row.Cells[5].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

    }
}
```

AND I USE THIS ONROWCREATED TO INSERT A ROW FOOTER FOR EACH EMPLOYEE

```
 protected void gvDetails_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    bool Row = false;
    if ((EmployeeNo > 0) && (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EmployeeNo") != null))
    {
        if (EmployeeNo != Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EmployeeNo").ToString()))
            Row = true;
    }
    if ((EmployeeNo > 0) && (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EmployeeNo") == null))
    {
        Row = true;
        Index = 0;
    }
    if (Row)
    {
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow NewTotalRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        NewTotalRow.Font.Bold = true;
        NewTotalRow.Style.Add("Background-Color", "#dbdbdb");
        NewTotalRow.Style.Add("Color", "#444444");
        NewTotalRow.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        HeaderCell.Text = "";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        HeaderCell.Style.Add("Padding", "0px");
        HeaderCell.Text = "<table align='right' cellspacing='0' style='width:193px;'><tr><td style='text-align:left; width:122px;'>" + "Total Income:" + "</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:left; width:200px;'>" + "Total Deductions:" + "</td></tr></table>";

        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

        HeaderCell.Style.Add("Background-Color", "#b4e7e1");
        HeaderCell.Style.Add("Color", "#1C5E55");
        HeaderCell.Style.Add("Padding", "0px");
        HeaderCell.Text = "<table cellspacing='0' style='width:100px;'><tr><td style='text-align:right; width:80px;'>" + TotalPrice1.ToString("N") + "</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:right;'>" + TotalPrice1D.ToString("N") + "</td></tr></table>";
        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        HeaderCell.Style.Add("Background-Color", "#b5cbe7");
        HeaderCell.Style.Add("Color", "#3d566f");
        HeaderCell.Style.Add("Padding", "0px");
        HeaderCell.Text = "<table cellspacing='0' style='width:100px;'><tr><td style='text-align:right; width:80px;'>" + TotalPrice2.ToString("N") + "</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:right;'>" + TotalPrice2D.ToString("N") + "</td></tr></table>";
        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);


        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        HeaderCell.Text = "";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
        NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
        GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + Index, NewTotalRow);
        Index++;
        TotalPrice1 = 0;
        TotalPrice1D = 0;
        TotalPrice2 = 0;
        TotalPrice2D = 0;
    }
}
```

DESIGN CODE FOR THE GRIDVIEW

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" CellPadding="2" runat="server" ShowHeader="True" Width="1130px" GridLines="both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="datagrid" EmptyDataText= "No timekeeping transaction posted for this classification." DataKeyNames="EmployeeNo" 
                            ShowFooter="True" OnRowCreated="gvDetails_RowCreated"  OnRowDataBound="gvDetails_OnRowDatabound">
                            <EmptyDataRowStyle  BackColor="#E3EAEB" BorderColor="#1C5E55" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="#4B6C9E" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Employee Name" ItemStyle-ForeColor="#1C5E55" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" SortExpression="EmpName" ItemStyle-Width="427px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeNo" HeaderText="Employee No" ItemStyle-Width="341px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="AdjustmentCode" HeaderText="Adjustment Code" ItemStyle-Width="417px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />                                                                                         
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Adjustment" HeaderText="Adjustment Name" ItemStyle-Width="240px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="PHP_Amount" HeaderText="PHP Amount" ItemStyle-BackColor="#d1f1ed" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>  
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="USD_Amount" HeaderText="USD Amount" ItemStyle-BackColor="#d1dff1" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>                              
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TaxableNote" HeaderText="Taxable" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrencyCode" HeaderText="Currency" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />    
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="AdjType" HeaderText="Adjustment Type" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="16">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CssClass="delete-item nooutline" Width="16" Height="16" ToolTip="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("AdjustmentNo") %>' OnClick="lnkDelete_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>        
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="16">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CssClass="edit-item nooutline" Width="16" Height="16" ToolTip="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("AdjustmentNo") %>' OnClick="lnkEdit_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNotes" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Notes") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>                                                                    
                            </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

THIS IS THE EDIT BUTTON Click Event

```
protected void lnkEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkSender = (LinkButton)sender;
    hdnAdjustmentID.Value = lnkSender.CommandArgument.ToString();
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lnkSender.NamingContainer;
    popuAdjustment();
    hdnNewEdit.Value = "Edit";
    divSearchNew.Visible = false;
    lblEditTitle.Text = "Edit Payroll Adjustment";
    HiddenField hdnNotes = (HiddenField)gvRow.FindControl("hdnNotes");
    string payPeriod = cutoffClass.getActivePayrollPeriod();
    txtFrom.Text = payPeriod.Split('-')[0].ToString().Trim();
    txtTo.Text = payPeriod.Split('-')[1].ToString().Trim();
    lblSearchEmpName.Text = gvRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim();
    lblSearchEmpNo.Text = gvRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString().Trim();
    txtNotes.Text = hdnNotes.Value;
    string adjCode = gvRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim();
    //drpAdjCode.SelectedValue = String.Compare(drpAdjCode.SelectedValue, adkCpde, false);
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li in drpAdjCode.Items)
    {
        if (li.Value.Trim().ToUpper() == adjCode.Trim().ToUpper())
        {
            li.Selected = true;
        }

    }

    string tax = gvRow.Cells[6].Text.ToString().Trim();
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li in drptaxable.Items)
    {
        if (li.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == tax.ToUpper())
        {
            li.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            li.Selected = false;
        }
    }

    string adjType = gvRow.Cells[8].Text.ToString().Trim();
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li in rdoAdjType.Items)
    {
        if (li.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == adjType.ToUpper())
        {
            li.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            li.Selected = false;
        }
    }

    string curr = gvRow.Cells[7].Text.ToString();
    drpCurr.SelectedValue = curr;
    decimal amount = 0;
    if (curr == "PHP")
    {
        amount = Convert.ToDecimal(gvRow.Cells[4].Text.ToString());
    }
    else if (curr == "USD")
    {
        amount = Convert.ToDecimal(gvRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString());
    }
    txtAmount.Text = amount.ToString();
    modalNew.Show();
}
```

Comment: We really can't help much unless you show some code.

Comment: Where is the part that pertains to those buttons? That is the part we needed to see.

Comment: Ive added it.. please see last 2 code blocks

Comment: do not see stange code,maybe you can debug it and see the abnormal button has correctly fire the server event?

Comment: I tried tracing it, but it does not pass through he traced line

Comment: even can not fire the lnkEdit_Click ?

Comment: No. The button circled in green does not fire lnkEdit_Click. This is strange

Comment: I tried OnRowCommand but did not work either

Comment: I tried adding a button without an event, when I clicked it and it postback..the same thing happens on the grid when the edit/delete button is clicked. It just binds but disregards the onrowcreated and onrowdatabound events of the gridview

Comment: I have no idea. maybe the button cause some js error? maybe  check your  browser console

Comment: Same process flow works on other module, I used same js. How can I check browser console?

Comment: Hi. I removed all the javascript and jquery in my project. Still not working.

Comment: Can this affect `MaxHttpCollectionKeys`

Comment: I tried changing the MaxHttpCollectionKeys but still got same problem